# remove parent id record if column contains that `id` in parent column mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table and records like below

**templates**

```
id       name         parent

1        template1    0
2        template2    0
3        template3    1
```

And i want output like this,

```
id       name         parent

2        template2    0
3        template3    1
```

As you can see #3 has parent #1, so need to deselect that from query using single query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NOT EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * FROM templates t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM templates s
                 WHERE s.parent = t.id)
```

Or a `LEFT JOIN` :

```
SELECT t.* FROM templates t
LEFT JOIN templates s
 ON(t.id = s.parent)
WHERE s.id is null
```

Or `NOT IN()` :

```
SELECT * FROM templates t
WHERE t.id NOT IN(SELECT parent FROM templates)
```

Comment: hi, you answer did job for me, but i  want some suggestion from you. if i am using query like this `WHERE t.id NOT IN(SELECT parent FROM templates) and status=`1` its not working for me, seems AND clause not working with `NOT IN` ?

Comment: No, there is no problem on combining `NOT IN` with anything. Maybe something with your data.. Post an example where it doesn't work and I'll tell you why. @HimanshuBhardiya

Answer (score 2):

Try this;)

```
select t1.*
from templates t1
left join templates t2 on t1.id = t2.parent
where t2.id is null
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9971/1)

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

```
SELECT * FROM `templates` where id NOT IN (SELECT parent FROM `templates` where parent!=0 GROUP BY parent);
```